# Number is not counting up by 1 at all

Tags: php

Aftr a submit code is run it should perform this code below:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])) {
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
            $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
 }
 else if (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && 
       $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
 }

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

When I echo the code below:

```
<?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_count'] ?>
```

Everytime a submit button is clicked on, if the number for `$sessionMinus` is less than the number `$_SESSION['initial_count']`, then it should the number for `$sessionMinus` by 1 each time the page has been submitted.

But it is not adding the number by 1 at all. `$sessionMinus` just keeps outputting '1' each time page is submitted. What do I need to change in my code?

I performed a `var_dump($_SESSION);` and this is what it outputted:

```
array(3) { 
   ["sessionCount"]=> int(1) 
   ["initial_count"]=> string(1) "5" 
   ["sessionNum"]=> int(5) 
}
```

Comment: Did you ask this question before?

Comment: I imagine your elseif condition is never being met. A var_dump($_POST) might be helpful here.

Comment: @JvdBerg I have not asked this before? has anyone asked similar question? This is an exercise question off a portfolio I am following but struggling to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure `sessionCount` isset in the `else if` statement? `var_dump` just before `and` after the addition and look at the result.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) gives me this array(0) { }, so your right elseif statement is not being reached. Do you know why it isn't being met?

Comment: Because either `$_POST['sessionNum']` is set, OR `$_POST['submitDetails']` is not set. (or both)

Comment: I think the else part is never evaluated. You click the button and al inputs are send to the server in the $_POST array.

`isset($_POST['sessionNum'])` wil always evaluate to true, and the else is never called. 

No idea what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Krycke When I do a var_dump($_SESSION['sessionCount']) before the else if statement. I get a parse error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in /web/.../Mobile_app/Text5.php on line 36`. Am I using the wrong syntax for elseif in php?

Comment: @JvdBerg What I am trying to do is that if the user accesses this page for the first time (or is navigated to this page), then `$sessionMinus` starts at '1' aka if statement is met. If the user then submits the page (page submits to itself), then it should follow the else if statement and add a number by 1 so that now the number is '2' for `$sessionMinus`. Submit page again then `$sessionMinus` is '3' and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug it as follows:

```
session_start();

var_dump( $_POST, $_SESSION ); //See that the post and session parameters you think should be there, really are there.
if(isset($_POST['sessionNum'])) {
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
            $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
 }
 else if (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && 
       $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    var_dump( $_SESSION['sessionCount'] ); //check the current count (and that you really are here.
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
    var_dump( $_SESSION['sessionCount'] ); // Check that the count is updated correctly.
 }

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

Comment: After debugging thanks to your code, this is wha it outputs: `array(0) { } array(3) { ["sessionCount"]=> int(1) ["initial_count"]=> string(1) "4" ["sessionNum"]=> int(4) } array(0) { } array(3) { ["sessionCount"]=> int(1) ["initial_count"]=> string(1) "4" ["sessionNum"]=> int(4) }`

Comment: Looks like you don't have any $_POST variables, meaning, non of the above if/else statements will be true.

Comment: I have found out where the problem is. The problem is actually in my jquery code. I will mark this answer and set up a new question but it is very strange how the jquery function affects the php code

Comment: You have nothing in the $_POST variable. The $_POST variable will be populated if for instance a form has been posted and it's action is to send information to POST. It's looks like something like that has not happened. Where are you hoping to get the information `sessionNum` from?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment, I think this is what you are after:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['sessionCount']) || !$_SESSION['sessionCount'] ) {
    //Declare my counter for the first time

    $_SESSION['initial_count'] = $_POST['sessionNum'];
    $_SESSION['sessionNum'] = intval($_POST['sessionNum']);
    $_SESSION['sessionCount'] = 1;
 }
 else if (isset($_POST['submitDetails']) && 
       $_SESSION['sessionCount'] < $_SESSION['sessionNum']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCount']++;
 }

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCount'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort JvdBerg but it hasn't worked. I still outputs '1'. Also in `$_SESSION['sessionCount']` if typed in the page before '3' and then navigate to this page, it doesn't change the number, it sticks to last number which is '4' as 4 was the previous number before I included your code and refreshed the browser. The var_dump($_POST) and var_dump($_SESSION) outputs this: `array(0) { } array(3) { ["sessionCount"]=> int(1) ["initial_count"]=> string(1) "4" ["sessionNum"]=> int(4) }`

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['sessionCount']) before the else if statement outputs `int(1) `